# Rails : The right path to go to the usershow view I added as friend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I create a following system exactly like that with users (Devise). I followed the Ryan Bates Rails casts http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

In this code we can add friends and delete friends. I create a `user#show` view to manage their accounts.

I want to create a `link_to` on the picture and name friend I added to go to his/her profile.

When I add a friend I want to display it like in my show view here

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" >
  <% for friendship in @user.friendships %>
     <li class="col-sm-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset">
       <div class="friend-picture">
       <%=h image_tag friendship.friend.picture %>
          </div>
          <h6>
            <%=h friendship.friend.first_name %> <%=h friendship.friend.last_name[0] %>.
              <%= link_to friendship, :method => :delete do %>
              <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
            <% end %>
          </h6>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

The migration is called FriendShip

```
class CreateFriendships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friendships do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The model for `User` is

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
```

The model for `Friendship` is

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

The `Friendship` controller

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end

def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Removed friendship."
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" >
<% @user.friendships.each do |friendship| %>
  <li class="col-sm-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset">
    <div class="friend-picture">
      <%= link_to user_path(friendship.friend) do %>
        <%= h image_tag friendship.friend.picture %>
      <% end %>  
    </div>
    <h6>
      <%= link_to user_path(friendship.friend) do %>
        <%=h friendship.friend.first_name %> <%=h friendship.friend.last_name[0] %>
      <% end %>  
      <%= link_to friendship, :method => :delete do %>
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
      <% end %>
    </h6>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I also update the `for` loop to the `each`, which is more `ruby` way.

Comment: Thank you @Dharam why It doesn't work with `for`? I don't understand.

Comment: I didn't say `for` loop does't work. Its just that using `each` for iteration is the `ruby` way.

Comment: Ok because it was the problem for the `link_to`